# Заменить несколько данных в строке, используя массив

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется строка: "/catalog/mebel/divany/"
Имеется массив: $trans["mebel" => "Мебель", "divany" => "Диваны"]
Нужно из строки транслит превратить в кириллицу, чтобы получилось "/catalog/Мебель/Диваны/"
Понимаю, что нужно использовать str_replace, но не доходит как это сделать в случае с подобным массивом. Или есть другой способ?
Спасибо.

Comment: а такой вариант `"/catalog/".$trans["mebel"]."/".$trans["divany"]."/"` не подходит?

Comment: Скорее всего нет или я просто что-то не понимаю. Мне нужно объяснить скрипту, что там где встречается слово mebel нужно заменить его на слово Мебель, а там где слово divany, нужно заменить его на слово Диваны. А слова эти встречаются в тексте в разных местах. Копаю в сторону array_search() сейчас.

Comment: Ну вы пишите "есть строка", а теперь по факту получается "есть текст, в котором встречается строка". В вопросе такое обязательно надо учитывать.

Comment: @MasterAlex, учту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str =  "/catalog/mebel/divany/";
$trans = ["mebel" => "Мебель", "divany" => "Диваны"];

echo str_replace(array_keys($trans), array_values($trans), $str);
```

array_keys - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php

array_values - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php

str_replace с массивами пример - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-examples

Comment: Спасибо большое. То что нужно!